# Laravel relationship method not working

Tags: php, laravel

after spending hours on solving this issue I want to ask you for help.

I have the following structure:

**Model:** Student.php

```
class Student extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'studenten';

    public function kurs() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Kurs::class);
    }
}
```

**Model:** Kurs.php

```
class Kurs extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'kurse';

    public function studenten() {
        return $this->hasMany(Student::class);
    }
}
```

**Controller:** KursController.php

```
class KursController extends Controller
{
    public function showStudenten() {
        return view('example.studenten', [
            'kurse' => Kurs::all(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

**View:** example\studenten.blade.php

```
@foreach($kurse as $kurs)
    <p>{{ $kurs->title }}, {{ $kurs->id }}</p>
    @foreach($kurs->studenten() as $student)) 
      <p>{{ $student->name }}</p>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

**Table:** kurse

```
id | title | created_at | updated at
```

**Table:** studenten

```
id | name | kurs_id | created_at | updated_at
```

I'm trying to output the students belonging to every course. Where is my error? I tried to specify the foreign key *'kurs_id'* in my model methods but it won't work.
Could you please help me to find my mistake?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I get no error but nothing is displayed despite the "Kurse"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

In Your Controller

```
 public function showStudenten() {
    return view('example.studenten', [
        'kurse' => Kurs::with('studenten')->get(),
    ]);
}
```

In your view file

```
@foreach($kurse as $kurs)
 <p>{{ $kurs->title }}, {{ $kurs->id }}</p>
   @foreach($kurs->studenten as $student)) 
    <p>{{ $student->name }}</p>
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: I tried this before with no effect but now it seems to work. Thank you very much! Could you explain why I don't need the () here, please?

Comment: @Johannes - `studenten` is an array not a function

Comment: It will return object of array , in Laravel's eloquent function you need not to use (). It return object